# jQuery in Wordpress - Hide parent div if it contains a specific other div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, slick.js

I'm trying to hide a slick slider section if it has no slides. I've tried tons of different options, like trying to use PHP and CSS, but I feel I'm closest to getting it to work with jQuery.

The HTML output structure is:

```
<div class="container-flex type-testimonials-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container type-testimonials slick-initialized slick-slider">
            <div class="slick-list draggable">
                <div class="slick-track">
                
                    <div class="slick-slide">
                        SINGLE SLIDE CONTENT
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="slick-slide">
                        SINGLE SLIDE CONTENT
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="slick-slide">
                        SINGLE SLIDE CONTENT
                    </div>
                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, I'm thinking I can use jQuery to hide the containing div (.type-testimonials-container) if the single slide div (.slick-slide) doesn't exists.

I have tried the following:

```
if(jQuery(".slick-slide").html().length)
{
jQuery(".type-testimonials-container").hide();
}
```

As well as lots of variations of that... I think it might be because the two divs aren't on the same level and one contains the other, but trying to find a parent/child way of doing is proving difficult... I'm not sure which way to go...

Any help would be massively appreciated!

********EDIT*********

I've also tried checking the parent and child relationship and trying to wait until the DOM has loaded, like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    var parentDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("slick-track");
    var childDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("slick-slide");
    
    if (parentDiv.contains(childDiv)) 
    {
      alert("div DOES exist");
    }
    else{
      alert("div DOES NOT exist");
    }

});
```

But this just shows me the DOES NOT exist alert even though it does exist - Will this search the whole of the DOM for it? or do I need to provide the exact path of the div from body or something?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just query for the length of the HTML collection of `.slick-slide`? JQ will still return an object if the target element doesn't exist, and the object will have a property `length`. Something like

```
if(jQuery(".slick-slide").length === 0) {
  jQuery(".type-testimonials-container").hide();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this :) Ive tried that I believe, but I've just tried again and it seems to remove the strip completely, even if it contains .slick-slide

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it this way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    if(jQuery('.slick-slide').length){
        jQuery('.type-testimonials-container').show();
    }

    else
    {
    jQuery('.type-testimonials-container').hide();
    }

});
```